# E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/extended_states (1)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt

I have similar problem as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139441/reading-package-lists...error! This question is found in many posts but I did the 2 solutions provided and same problem exists... What should I do?

Problem description image:
[image: problem description image]

I am using WSL with the following configuration:
[image: WSL configuration image]

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Ubuntu? Also, you can run Ubuntu from USB, without installation.

Comment: I will try this as last solution , Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as pointed by [@drmoishe-pippik](https://superuser.com/users/401553/drmoishe-pippik) re-installing solved the issue !